# Strange behaviour of `==` and `in` in a single line python statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, logical-operators

```
def foo1():
   return True == 3 in [1,2,3]

def foo2():
    return 3 in [1,2,3] == True

def foo3():
     return True == ( 3 in [1,2,3] )

def foo4():
   return ( 3 in [1,2,3] ) == True
```

```
foo1() => False
foo2() => False
foo3() => True
foo4() => True
```

```
import dis

dis.dis(foo1)

  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (True)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
              4 DUP_TOP
              6 ROT_THREE
              8 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             10 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    18
             12 LOAD_CONST               5 ((1, 2, 3))
             14 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   18 ROT_TWO
             20 POP_TOP
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

```
dis.dis( foo2 )
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
              4 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              8 BUILD_LIST               3
             10 DUP_TOP
             12 ROT_THREE
             14 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             16 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    24
             18 LOAD_CONST               4 (True)
             20 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   24 ROT_TWO
             26 POP_TOP
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

```
>>> dis.dis( foo3 )
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (True)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
              4 LOAD_CONST               5 ((1, 2, 3))
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              8 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

```
>>> dis.dis( foo4 )
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              2 LOAD_CONST               5 ((1, 2, 3))
              4 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              6 LOAD_CONST               4 (True)
              8 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

From the disassemble code I can see the `foo1()` should return `False` since it won't execute the `in` comparison and hence `False`.

But what happens to foo2(), why does this return False?

Whereas foo3() and foo4() works perfectly as we can be confirmed from the disassembled code.

Ref: https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html

Python2.7

I've seen similar behavior python3+; the disassembled code is different but logic seems to be same in the disassembled code.

Python operator precedence:
https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Operator precedence for`==` and `in` is same but it doesn't match the expectation.

Answer (score 3):

Both `in` and `==` are relation operators, and relational operators in Python chain. `3 in [1, 2, 3] == True` performs both `3 in [1, 2, 3]` and `[1, 2, 3] == True` simultaneously.

But you shouldn't be comparing against booleans regardless. Pass the result to `bool()` if you need to, but `in` already results in a boolean.

Comment: Oh! So silly missed that :(

Comment: just in case here is the link to the doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons